# IOS - How to create Facebook reaction bar with blur background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Although it may not be the week to replicate some design of Facebook, I would like to be able to design my own version of the reaction indicator view below.

[image]

I have three `UIImageView`s lined in the same positions as above. The problem is that, unlike Facebook, the background color may change (i.e is on top of a `UIBlurEffect`) and therefore I am unable to set the border color to white.

I thought it would make sense to set the `borderColor` like so:

```
imageViewOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
imageViewOne.layer.borderWidth = 2
```

However, the underlying `imageViewTwo` is displayed in the border instead of the background color.

So far, I have this:

[image]

Would appreciate some help/ideas on how to make this work - I'm thinking of masks but not sure whether a. this is the correct solution and b. how to achieve the desired effect. To clarify, I am not able to set the border color as a constant as it will change with the `UIBlurEffect`.

Comment: I'm not saying _duplicate_ but you definitely take a look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332817/transparent-ring-in-ios/25333250#25333250, it may lead to your desired solution.

Comment: Hi @Alexander MacLeod, If my answer is right, feel free to provide bounty for my answer ;)

Comment: Hi @trungduc I had to wait for the bounty time limit before I could award the reputation

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderMacLeod, now I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, there are 2 way to resolve your problem.

- Create and use clipped image for `Wow` and `Love` like below `Love` image.

  [image]
- Another way is using [mask property of `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask). Creating a mask image and apply it for `mask` property.

  Mask image looks like.

  [image]

  Code for applying `mask`.

  ```
  let imvLoveMask = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "MASK_IMAGE_NAME"));
  imvLoveMask.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: imvLove.frame.size.width, height: imvLove.frame.size.height);
  imvLove.mask = imvLoveMask;
  ```

Both of 2 above way can help you achieve what you want in the question. Background of icons in below image is an `UIVisualEffectView`.

[image]

In my opinion, the first way with clipped image is better and faster because you don't need to apply mask for your imageView. But if you don't want to create a clipped image for some reason, you can use the second way.

For more detail, you can take a look at [my demo repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/facebook-reaction-bar)

Answer (score 2):

You need to clip part of the image in order to let underlying content be visible in the gaps between images. See playground sample.

Add smile_1, smile_2, smile_3 images to playground resources. I took emoji images from https://emojipedia.org/facebook/.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class EmojiView: UIView {
   var imageView = UIImageView()
   var imageInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3.0, left: 3.0, bottom: 3.0, right: 3.0)
   var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
   var overlap: CGFloat = 0.0 {
      didSet {
         self.updateShape()
      }
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      self.setup()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }

   // MARK: UIView
   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      self.setup()
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      self.imageView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, self.imageInset)
      self.shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
      self.updateShape()
   }

   // MARK: Private
   private func setup() {
      self.addSubview(self.imageView)
      self.layer.mask = self.shapeLayer
   }

   private func updateShape() {
      let frame = self.bounds
      let path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame)
      // Cut off part of the image if overlap more then > 0
      if 0 < self.overlap {
         path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
         path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: -frame.width + self.overlap, y: 0.0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)).reversing())
      }
      self.shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
   }
}

let overlap: CGFloat = 10 // Amount of pixels emojis overlap each other

// Create emoji views
let emojiView_1 = EmojiView(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
emojiView_1.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "smile_1")

let emojiView_2 = EmojiView(frame: CGRect(x: emojiView_1.frame.maxX - overlap, y: 5.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
emojiView_2.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "smile_2")
emojiView_2.overlap = overlap

let emojiView_3 = EmojiView(frame: CGRect(x: emojiView_2.frame.maxX - overlap, y: 5.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
emojiView_3.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "smile_3")
emojiView_3.overlap = overlap

let holderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: emojiView_3.frame.maxX + 5, height: 50.0))

// Add gradient layer
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = holderView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
holderView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

// Add emoji views
holderView.addSubview(emojiView_1)
holderView.addSubview(emojiView_2)
holderView.addSubview(emojiView_3)

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = holderView
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
self.imageViewOne.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageViewOne.layer.bounds.width/2
self.imageViewOne.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. I know how to create the circle mask, but the I am unable to achieve the overlapping border effect as the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually instead of masking, you can put your images in a view which has white background and round(set corner radius). Then you can put these views (which has white background and images in it) via settings their [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) or on storyboard with view hierarchy.

I've prepared a little playground for you. You can see the result in the screenshot. I've put a view inside the containerViews instead you can use uiimageview etc. It's a bit ugly but solves your issue I guess it's up to you to decide how use it.

[image]

Here is the code, you can just copy and paste it to a new playground and test it.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var mainContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 80))
mainContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

var containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = containerView.frame.width / 2

var innerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60))
innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
innerView.layer.cornerRadius = innerView.frame.width / 2

containerView.addSubview(innerView)

var containerView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
containerView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
containerView2.layer.cornerRadius = containerView2.frame.width / 2

var innerView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60))
innerView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
innerView2.layer.cornerRadius = innerView2.frame.width / 2

containerView2.addSubview(innerView2)

containerView.layer.zPosition = 2
containerView2.layer.zPosition = 1

mainContainerView.addSubview(containerView)
mainContainerView.addSubview(containerView2)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainContainerView
```

Comment: The background color is a gradient and therefore it cannot be white.

Comment: then make background color gradient. Issue is not about the color issue is about positioning views hierarchy to make it look like they are on top of each other.

Comment: would you be able to provide me with some example code as I am struggling to understand what your solution is?

Comment: Thanks for you code. The problem is I would like to have the mainContainerView's gradient (in my case a uivisualeffectview) to be matched by each container view.

Comment: In that case put uivisualeffectview in mainContainerView this will do the job. Also if my solution solves your problem please mark as accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't though. If you put a visual effect view as the background for the main container view, the container view is still white and hides the background. If you set it to clear you remove the effect, if you set it to another visual effect view, it becomes darker than the background as two visual effect views overlap.

Comment: so change mainContainerView with uivisualeffectview and add the other view as subview to it. var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 80))
visualEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
visualEffectView.contentView.addSubview(containerView)
visualEffectView.contentView.addSubview(containerView2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167652/discussion-between-alexander-macleod-and-mkeremkeskin).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple suggestion**: As you are setting border color programatically, you have a control to change it, according to background color (if background color is solid (not a gradient)).

```
imageViewOne.layer.borderColor = imageViewOne.superview?.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.white
imageViewOne.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: The background color is a UIBlurEffect so essentially it is a gradient.