# How to draw a circle around UICollectionViewCell when clicking on it and remove others circle from previous selected cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I've been working with UICollectionView lately. There is a requirement that needs to be implemented like: "There are several imageviews in several collectionview cell. When user selects one of the image/cell, the app will draw a blue circle around that image/cell."
Currently, I'm able to do the draw on the cell. But the problem now is that I am able only to draw all cells but not one cell at the time (as screenshot below)

[image]

So my question is: **how can I select one image/cell, the blue circle of previous selected cell should be removed?**

Thanks so much for the answers in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code, how you draw the circles?

Comment: I created a CircleView class like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebmil1hd6yh11ua/CircleView.swift?dl=0

And here are how i draw it on the cell: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzg1rvqhcaz6o7j/ContentWalletCollectionViewCell.swift?dl=0

Comment: This is not even close to a duplicate of [Transparent Ring in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332817/transparent-ring-in-ios). This question isn't asking how to draw the ring; the asker already knows how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

[image: demo]

You didn't say how you're putting the blue circle in the cell. Here's how I think you should handle selection: use the collection view's built-in selection support as much as possible.

A `UICollectionView` already has support for selecting cells. By default, its  `allowsSelection` property is true and its `allowsMultipleSelection` property is false, so it allows the user to select one item at a time by tapping the item. This sounds like almost exactly what you want.

The collection view makes the current selection available in its `indexPathsForSelectedItems` property, which is either nil or empty when no cell is selected, and contains exactly one index path when one item is selected.

When an item is selected, and there is a visible cell for the item, the cell shows that its item is selected by making its `selectedBackgroundView` visible. So make a `UIView` subclass that shows a blue circle:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let layer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = nil
        let width: CGFloat = 3
        layer.lineWidth = width
        layer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: width / 2, dy: width / 2), transform: nil)
    }
}
```

Then use an instance of `CircleView` as the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`. You can create the instance lazily the first time the cell becomes selected:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet {
            if newValue && selectedBackgroundView == nil {
                selectedBackgroundView = CircleView()
            }
        }
    }

    var title: String = "???" {
        didSet {
            label.text = title
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet private var label: UILabel!
}
```

With this code in place, the user can tap a cell to select its item, and the cell will show a blue circle when selected. Tapping another cell will deselect the previously-selected item, and the blue circle will “move” to the newly-selected item's cell.

You might want to let the user deselect the selected item by tapping it again. `UICollectionView` doesn't do that by default if `allowsMultipleSelection` is false. One way to enable tap-again-to-deselect is by implementing `collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemAt:)` in your `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []).contains(indexPath) {
            // Item is already selected, so deselect it.
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. Your code does work. Sorry for unclear title.